# Pass String from VBA to C DLL to Modify as a Parameter and Return

Tags: c, vba, string, dll, parameter-passing

My journey learning about C DLL's and their interaction with VBA continues. The setup is I want to pass a string to the C DLL as a parameter, have the DLL modify the string, and return a return code as a long AND have the modified string be accessible in VBA. I think I have tried every iteration of strcpy_s and SysReAllocString there is on the internet and I can't get it. I can end up with a modified string in C but then the DLL IDE crashes on the return to VBA (or I assume it is because VBA crashes). Here is some code to help the conversation along... Also bonus point for helping to display my string in a C message box so I can validate things are working..

C Code

```
long DLL_EXPORT __stdcall string_change_test(char* string1, long string1_length, char* string2, long string2_length) /* function declaration */
{
    long return_result;
    return_result = 314159;
    char* NewString = "Hello world from Timer DLL!";
    size_t NewStringLength = strlen(NewString);

    MessageBoxA(NULL, (LPCSTR)(string1), "String1 Contents", MB_OK);
    //strcpy_s(string1, NewStringLength, "Hellow World from Timer DLL!");
    //strcpy_s(string1, NewStringLength, NewString);
    //SysReAllocString(*string1, "Hello world from Timer DLL!");
    MessageBoxA(NULL, string1, "String1 Modified Contents", MB_OK);
    //MessageBoxA(NULL, (LPCSTR)(*string1), "String1 Changed Contents", MB_OK);
    
    return return_result;
```

VBA Code

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function string_change_test Lib "C:\Users\micha\source\repos\CalculationsDll in C\x64\Debug\CalculationsDll in C.dll" (StringValue1 As String, StringValue1_Length As Long, StringValue2 As String, StringValue2_Length As Long) As LongPtr
'
Function DLL_String_Testing()

    Dim StringValue1 As String
    Dim StringValue2 As String
    Dim StringValue1_Length As Long
    Dim StringValue2_Length As Long
    Dim StringValuePTR1 As LongPtr
    Dim StringValuePTR2 As LongPtr
    Dim StringResult As LongPtr
       
    StringValue1 = "Hello world from Timer DLL"
    StringValue1_Length = Len(StringValue1)
    StringValuePTR1 = StrPtr(StringValue1)
    
    StringValue2 = "Have Fun"
    StringValue2_Length = Len(StringValue2)
    StringValuePTR2 = StrPtr(StringValue2)
    
    
    StringResult = string_change_test(StringValue1, StringValue1_Length, StringValue2, StringValue2_Length)
    
    test = 0
    
End Function
```

As you can see I've tried a lot of things hence the extra code I include in case I was on the right track at some point.

Comment: `Declare StringValue1() as Byte`. A Byte array. `StringValue1 = "Hello world from Timer DLL" & ChrW(0)` a unicode byte array. Remember to add `ChrW(0)` to the end of your string. Now pass the FIRST byte (`StringValue1(0)` `ByRef`. Use `MsgBoxW`.

Comment: Ok, that worked for my messagebox issue. Thank you! 

Ended up with this in my C 
`MessageBoxW(NULL, (LPCWSTR)(string1), L"String1 Contents", MB_OK);`